# Matching a unique chars once in a line

Tags: c#, regex, string, char

```
string uniquechars = "a,e,i"
            int counting = 0;
            foreach (var item in line)
            {
                if (chars.IndexOf(item) != -1)
                {
                    counting++;
                }
            }
```

This code finds how many times a specific char is inside a string, but I don't really understand how I should make it count each letter only once. For example `aaaaeeeeiiii` is the line and I want the output to be `Number of unique letters appeared that appeared: 3`

For 3 chars I could make an if , but that would be inefficient if I had about 8 unique characters and they were case sensetive too.

---

## Solved

Thanks to a comment I figured it out in a simple way. Here's how I got it:

```
            char[] seperators = { ' ', '.', ',', '!', '?', ':', ';', '(', ')', '\t' };
        string chars = "A;E,I.Y;O;U;a;e;i;y;o;u;Ą;ą;Ę;ę;Ė;ė;Į;į;Ų;ų;Ū;ū";
        string[] Uniquechars = chars.Split(seperators);
        int counting = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Uniquechars.Length; i++)
        {
            if (eil.Contains(Uniquechars[i])) counting++;
            
        }
```

Comment: so basically you want to "go through each uniquechar sequence" and check `if(line.Contains(one of the uniquechars))` then => count your counter up... sorry for the weird pseudo code, but this should get you startet

Comment: one more tip. You should collect your unique chars in a collection, not a string

Comment: Thanks this was really simple and I got it now.

Comment: `Thanks to a comment I figured it out in a simple way. If anyone needs, here's how I got it...` Please put your answer in the answer section (below) - not in your question.

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer of its own, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can just count the distinct characters:

```
var count = chars.Distinct().Count(char.IsLetter);
```